# knockoutjs - custom template is binded with parent content

Tags: templates, knockout.js

I have a problem using knockoutjs with custom template bindings.

Suppose I have a HTML body like this:

```
<div id="1">
    <div data-bind="template:{name: '2', data: data}"></div>
</div>

<div id="2">
    <h3 data-bind="text: caption"></h3>
</div>
```

JS code looks like this:

```
var ViewModel2 = function () {
    this.caption = ko.observable("Caption");
}

var ViewModel1 = function () {
    this.data = new ViewModel2();
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel1(), document.getElementById("1"));
```

If we test this code, everything will work just fine;
See JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/4eTWW/33/

Now suppose we want to make our custom template binding. We'll use 'templatex' binding instead of 'template'.

In HTML we need to change just one line:

```
<div data-bind="templatex:{name: '2', data: data}"></div>
```

Next, let's add custom template binding to JS:

```
/*Custom binding*/
ko.bindingHandlers.templatex = {
   init: function (element) {
       ko.bindingHandlers.template.init.apply(this, arguments);
   },

   update: ko.bindingHandlers.template.update
}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/4eTWW/35/

But in this case we have an error, saying that it can't find 'caption' in the model.

Now let's add template {} to html bindings:

```
<div data-bind="template: {}, templatex:{name: '2', data: data}"></div>
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/4eTWW/36/

And now everything works just fine.

It seems that while binding parent div it can't determine that child div is a template.

So how can I mark it as a template in my custom template binder?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to return the value of the template bindings `init` function.  It returns a flag called `controlsDescendantBindings` which tells KO that you will handle binding its children.  Otherwise, it will continue to try to bind the child elements with the current data context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrong update handler, change to this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.templatex= {
    init: function(element) {
        // do things
        return ko.bindingHandlers.template.init.apply(this, arguments);
    },

    update: function(element) {
        return ko.bindingHandlers.template.update.apply(this, arguments);
    }
}
```

Here is working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vyshniakov/4eTWW/39/

Comment: Previous variant also works, but it's required to return the value.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use a custom binding to create a new template engine. You need to register your custom engine with `ko.setTemplateEngine()`.

From the knockoutjs source:

```
If you want to make a custom template engine,

[1] Inherit from the ko.templateEngine class (like ko.nativeTemplateEngine does)
[2] Override 'renderTemplateSource', supplying a function with this signature:

       function (templateSource, bindingContext, options) {
           // - templateSource.text() is the text of the template you should render
           // - bindingContext.$data is the data you should pass into the template
           //   - you might also want to make bindingContext.$parent, bindingContext.$parents,
           //     and bindingContext.$root available in the template too
           // - options gives you access to any other properties set on "data-bind: { template: options }"
           //
           // Return value: an array of DOM nodes
       }

[3] Override 'createJavaScriptEvaluatorBlock', supplying a function with this signature:

       function (script) {
           // Return value: Whatever syntax means "Evaluate the JavaScript statement 'script' and output the result"
           //               For example, the jquery.tmpl template engine converts 'someScript' to '${ someScript }'
       }

    This is only necessary if you want to allow data-bind attributes to reference arbitrary template variables.
    If you don't want to allow that, you can set the property 'allowTemplateRewriting' to false (like ko.nativeTemplateEngine does)
    and then you don't need to override 'createJavaScriptEvaluatorBlock'.
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/6pStz/ (see Note 7 on this [page](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html))